# Is there a Visual Studio or Resharper shortcut to copy the current type and member to the clipboard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

For example...

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        // Cursor is here or on Method1
    }
}
```

I'd like a way to copy "TestClass.Method1" to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in feature to do just that, but there's something similar in ReSharper 8 - you can copy the XML-Doc ID to the clipboard, e.g. for:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Placing the caret on `Main` and then selecting this menu:

[image]

Will copy `M:ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])` to the clipboard.

Hope that (somewhat) helps...

Comment: Marvellous! Thanks Igal. It's for when I'm creating bugs and tasks that refer to specific areas of code. This will be really helpful.